# How to calculate price value and tax value in query

Tags: mysql, opencart

i try to filter product price when customer insert minimun value and maximum value.

**product.php**

```
public function getProducts($data = array()) {
....

if (!empty($data['min'])) {
    $sql .= " AND p.price BETWEEN '" .$data['min']. "' AND 9999 ";
}
```

with this code, category page will list out all products from price x until 9999.

The problem is some product has `tax` and the value is store in another table(`oc_tax_rate`). **So how to get final price of product in query ?** *(p.price + tax)* , something like this :

```
if (!empty($data['min'])) {
    $sql .= " AND final_price BETWEEN '" .$data['min']. "' AND 9999 ";
}
```

as i check page controller/category.php

```
$this->tax->calculate($result['price'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax'))
```

above code will return final price.

OC : v1.5.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, when You use a `min` and `max` filter values, Your query should not be choosing `between min and 9999` and `between 0 and max` but You should do this:

```
if (!empty($data['min'])) {
    $sql .= " AND p.price >= " . (int)$data['min'];
//                               ^^^^^ - against SQL injection!!!
}
```

and

```
if (!empty($data['max'])) {
    $sql .= " AND p.price <= " . (int)$data['max'];
//                               ^^^^^ - against SQL injection!!!
}
```

Also, as mentioned in the comment, do not forget to *cure* Your code against SQL injection!

Now, to Your real question: It is not possible to get the taxes and calculate taxed price along with products getting in one query. But You could do this in Your model - find this part of code

```
foreach ($query->rows as $result) {
    $product_data[$result['product_id']] = $this->getProduct($result['product_id']);
}
```

and we will modify it this way:

```
foreach ($query->rows as $result) {
    if (!empty($data['min']) 
            && $this->tax->calculate($result['price'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')) >= $data['min']) {
        $product_data[$result['product_id']] = $this->getProduct($result['product_id']);
    } else if (!empty($data['max']) 
            && $this->tax->calculate($result['price'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')) <= $data['max']) {
        $product_data[$result['product_id']] = $this->getProduct($result['product_id']);
    } else {
        $product_data[$result['product_id']] = $this->getProduct($result['product_id']);
    }
}
```

Comment: that awesome, thanks :D, i hope i will release free extension for opencart after fix this issue.